# Store result of a function in localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have an app that randomly generates stars and I want the stars to be unique for each visitor. I am achieving this with the following code.

```
// auto generation stuff 
  function makeid() {
    let r = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);

    return r;
  }

  let starList = [
    "red-giant",
    "red-supergiant",
    "blue-giant",
    "white-dwarf",
    "yellow-dwarf",
    "red-dwarf",
    "brown-dwarf",
  ];
  let posList = [
    "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
  ]
function RandomNum() {
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 3);
}
  const makeStars = (num  = 5) => {
    
    
   if (num > 0) {
        return (
          <div className="starWrapper">
            <Star
              name={`${makeid()}`}
            label={``}
              starType={`${starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)]} ${posList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1)]}`}
            ></Star>
           
           {makeStars((num - 1))}
          </div>
          
        );
        
   }
      };
```

And I am calling the function with the useEffect hook.

```
 useEffect(() => {
   setExoStars(makeStars(RandomNum())) 
  }, []);
```

This works fine, but the problem is the function runs every time the user visits the page. including when navigating though the app. I would like this function to run once and save the results while the user is navigating through the app.

I was experimenting with using localstorage

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('exoStars') === 'false') {
      setExoStars(makeStars(RandomNum()))
      localStorage.setItem('exoStars', exoStars);
    }
    else {
      localStorage.getItem('exoStars', exoStars)
    }
  }, []);
```

But so far all this accomplished is it prevents the function from running every time the user visits the page, but the results of the function are lost. How can I fix this problem? The full page is viewable [here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/planetviewer/blob/main/src/interstellar-view/interstellar.jsx).

Comment: I thought I had a solution but I didn't and yanked it. Sorry bout that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference state immediately after setting it. It takes a render cycle before the state is up to date, and it won't work in your use effect unless you add the state to your dependency array.

Try this:

```
const [exoStars, setExoStars] = useState<Star[]>();

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(exoStars); // undefined
  setExoStars(makeExoStars());
  console.log(exoStars); // still undefined!
}, [])
```

If you add `exoStars` to your dependency array, it will kind of work, except that you will log the previous state of exostars, and override it with your setter again.

Instead, get a variable, set your state if it is needed, and also assign it in local storage.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const savedStars = getStarsFromLocalStorage();
  if (savedStars) {
    setExoStars(savedStars);
    return;
  }

  const newStars = makeExoStars();
  saveStarsToLocalStorage(newStars)
  setExoStars(newStars)
}, [])
```

Comment: I tried to replicate this but I'm having the same results. And in your answer you said ```it will log the previous state of exoStars```, which would be fine. As long as it didn't overwrite anymore. 
My new code is viewable here https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/planetviewer/blob/main/src/interstellar-view/interstellar.jsx